# macro for Multiline text in cell to truncate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiline text in cell of specific column which has numbers followed by tab delimiter, i wish to work on below file please see name of SHEET

[LINK TO FILE](http://jmp.sh/v/LHA0OYzDw1xqZAQsc5BG)

actual data runs into more than 1000 rows, want to generate result output 1 and 2 in newly inserted column.

can any one help me with macro to run on specific column "ABC" and only keep text which is before tab and another column with two next character text concatenated. further this ABC column can change position in excel sheet I will be highly obliged if someone could help me.

Code I am Struck With is

```
Sub RahulSplit()
Dim colNum As Integer
    colNum = ActiveSheet.rows(1).Find(what:="ABC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "Results 2 Anticipated"

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\w*\t\w*\s"
        Dim x
        For Each x In .Execute(s)
            InBrackets = InBrackets & Mid(x, 2, Len(x) - 2) & vbLf
        Next
    End With

EndSub
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are currently having trouble with.  (And remove the link to an off-site file - questions should be self-contained and not rely on links that might break in the future.)

Comment: i agree but it was hard for specify the multiline text and it was just to make expert work on exact excel sheet.

Comment: @YowE3K I hope edits are acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this UDF to extract strings enclosed by `[...]` brackets:

```
Function InBrackets(s As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\[\w*\]"
        Dim x
        For Each x In .Execute(s)
            InBrackets = InBrackets & Mid(x, 2, Len(x) - 2) & vbLf
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

**Usage:**

B2 : `=InBrackets(A2)`

**EDIT**

Okay, so after you better specified your target, with nothing to do with the brackets, Try the follwing:

```
Sub InsertAnticipatedResults(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim colABC As Long, abc As Range
    With sh
        colABC = .Rows(1).Find(what:="ABC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        .Columns(colABC + 1).Insert
        .Cells(1, colABC + 1).value = "Results 1 Anticipated"

        .Columns(colABC + 2).Insert
        .Cells(1, colABC + 2).value = "Results 2 Anticipated"

        Set abc = .Range(.Cells(2, colABC), .Cells(.Rows.Count, colABC).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Dim res1 As String, res2 As String, result1 As String, result2 As String, x
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "^\S*\s*\S*\s"
        For Each abc In abc.Cells
            result1 = "": result2 = ""
            For Each x In .Execute(abc.Text)
                res2 = Trim(x)
                res1 = Trim(Left(res2, Len(res2) - 2))
                res2 = Replace(res2, " ", "")
                res2 = Replace(res2, vbTab, "")

                If Len(result1) > 0 Then result1 = result1 & vbLf: result2 = result2 & vbLf
                result1 = result1 & res1
                result2 = result2 & res2
            Next
            abc.Offset(, 1).value = result1
            abc.Offset(, 2).value = result2
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub Testing()
    InsertAnticipatedResults ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

[image: Test for Rahul]

Comment: thanks ASH but my requirement is slightly different i need data only which is starting word of each multiline e.g.  in   EP1189062           A1 2002-03-20 [EP1189062]  i want to have stating first set of word before tab i.e. EP1189062 in second column i want  to have two bunch of letter EP1189062           A1 concatenated together without space

Comment: please note that I have sheet which has column name so i am not bale to use A2 B2 kind references, stuck please help

Comment: your code works flawlessly for alphabets present in bracket but if in bracket '-' is present it wont work, it will be really suitable if you can tell me how to extact only first two words of each multiline  via macro, my colleagues have less idea to work on functions.

Comment: @RahulSharma As I suspected, your initital request was not obvious. The added part should achieve your desired results.

Comment: Can you help me with new question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422134/excel-parsing-multi-line-data-column-via-macro-with-concatenated-strings